# interrater-reliability with likert-scale and different raters

Tags: likert, agreement-statistics, intraclass-correlation

I am collecting data from a survey that includes a likert scale of 5 points. Each rater answers 18 questions (probably different questions). For each question I will have answers from 10 different raters. How can I calculate the interrater reliability, so that I can eliminate a rater who was giving random answers?

A rough example of the data, where x is the rater answer. 
[image]

One possible way, on a question level, calculate the difference between one rater's answer and the average of the answers of the other 9 raters for the same question, and have some threshold to eliminate raters. Or I can use intraclass correlation (ICC(1,k)) but how can I know which raters to eliminate? Or are there any other possible ways?

any help would be great,thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually used Krippendorf's alpha, following the intuition in this question. [Comparing inter-rater agreement between classes of raters](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132609/comparing-inter-rater-agreement-between-classes-of-raters)

Comment: Krippendorf's alpha is a good measure to use to help assess the idea of "agreement."